# Returning list of data from an Oracle stored procedure in ASP.NET Core

Tags: oracle, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

For manager approval, I've created a stored procedure in Oracle to get a list of employees with IDs and names. Then I called it in ASP.NET Core controller, but it only returned the last employee, not the entire list. When I try to call it back as cursor, it does not return anything.

```
create or replace PROCEDURE MANGERLIST
(
  EMPNO IN NUMBER 
, DG IN NUMBER 
, DEPT IN NUMBER 
, DESGN IN NUMBER 
,l_name OUT sys_refcursor
) AS 

  l_sql VARCHAR2(800);

BEGIN
  l_sql := 'select TRIM(emp_no) , TRIM(EMP_NAME_E) FROM hr."VempDtls" where DESG_TYPE <>99 ';

if DESGN in (4,5,6,99) then
    if EMPNO = 213 then
      l_sql := l_sql || 'and emp_no =85 ' ;    
    ELSif EMPNO in (341,215,278) then
        l_sql := l_sql||' and emp_no in(213,215,219,58) ';    
    ELSif EMPNO in (336,323) then
      l_sql := l_sql||' and emp_no in(277,219,58) ';    
    ELSE  
     l_sql := l_sql||' and (dg_code = DG and DESG_TYPE in (2,3,0,1) and emp_no <>EMPNO) OR (dg_code = DG  and dept_code = DEPT
            and DESG_TYPE in (4,5,6) and emp_no <>EMPNO and DESG_TYPE < DESGN) ';    
    end if;
 ELSif DESGN in (2,3) and EMPNO != 58 then 
       l_sql := l_sql||' and emp_no=120 ';
 else
      l_sql := l_sql;
end if;

   OPEN  l_name FOR l_sql;

END MANGERLIST;
```

This is my C# class:

```
public class MangerProc
{
    [NotMapped]
    public int inEMPNO { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public int inDG { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public int inDEPT { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public int inDESGN { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public int? Outl_id { get; set; }
    
    [StringLength(200)]
    [NotMapped]
    public string? Outl_name { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the function to call the stored procedure:

```
public virtual string  GetManagerList(int? empId, int? dg, int? dept, int? desgnation)
{
        try
        {
            using (var ctx = new hrmsContext())
            using (var cmd = ctx.Database.GetDbConnection().CreateCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.CommandText = "MANGERLIST";

                var EMPNOParam = new OracleParameter("EMP_NO", OracleDbType.Int32, empId, ParameterDirection.Input);
                var DGParam = new OracleParameter("inDG", OracleDbType.Int32, dg, ParameterDirection.Input);
                var DEPTParam = new OracleParameter("inDEPT", OracleDbType.Int32, dept, ParameterDirection.Input);
                var DESGNParam = new OracleParameter("inDESGN", OracleDbType.Int32, desgnation, ParameterDirection.Input);
                var l_idParam = new OracleParameter("Outl_id", OracleDbType.RefCursor, ParameterDirection.Output);

                cmd.Parameters.AddRange(new[] { EMPNOParam, DGParam, DEPTParam, DESGNParam, l_idParam });

                cmd.Connection.Open();
                var result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                cmd.Connection.Close();

                var assetRegistered = l_idParam.Value;
                return assetRegistered.ToString();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception x)
        {
            return null;
        }
}
```

sample Data

CREATE TABLE "HR"."VEMP_DTLS"
(
"EMP_NO" NUMBER,
"EMP_NAME_A" VARCHAR2(109 BYTE),
"DG_CODE" NUMBER,
"DEPT_CODE" NUMBER,
"DESG_TYPE" NUMBER

);

INSERT INTO "HR"."VEMP_DTLS" (EMP_NO, EMP_NAME_A, DG_CODE, DEPT_CODE, DESG_TYPE) VALUES ('278', 'Asma', '11', '11', '99')
INSERT INTO "HR"."VEMP_DTLS" (EMP_NO, EMP_NAME_A, DG_CODE, DEPT_CODE, DESG_TYPE) VALUES ('35', 'Ali', '11', '11', '2')
INSERT INTO "HR"."VEMP_DTLS" (EMP_NO, EMP_NAME_A, DG_CODE, DEPT_CODE, DESG_TYPE) VALUES ('127', 'Ahmed', '8', '4', '4')
INSERT INTO "HR"."VEMP_DTLS" (EMP_NO, EMP_NAME_A, DG_CODE, DEPT_CODE, DESG_TYPE) VALUES ('314', 'Mohammed', '11', '2', '4')
INSERT INTO "HR"."VEMP_DTLS" (EMP_NO, EMP_NAME_A, DG_CODE, DEPT_CODE, DESG_TYPE) VALUES ('215', 'Abudallah', '11', '11', '2')
INSERT INTO "HR"."VEMP_DTLS" (EMP_NO, EMP_NAME_A, DG_CODE, DEPT_CODE, DESG_TYPE) VALUES ('127', 'Saud', '9', '3', '4')

Comment: Please [edit] the question and include a [MRE] with: the `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements for your sample data; the inputs you use to call your procedure; the output that you are getting for those input; and the expected/desired output. This sounds like it is a problem with the data or the inputs but you have not provided either so we are unable to comment on them.

Comment: Offtopic. Why you have created this SP while it is easily doable via LINQ and will be much better maintainable?

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv because I use this SP in different Application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your procedure is invalid as you need to pass the variables as bind parameters (rather than trying to embed them in the string, which will compile but then fail at runtime):

```sql
create or replace PROCEDURE MANGERLIST
(
  EMPNO IN  NUMBER 
, DG    IN  NUMBER 
, DEPT  IN  NUMBER 
, DESGN IN  NUMBER 
,l_name OUT sys_refcursor
)
AS 
  l_sql VARCHAR2(800);
BEGIN
  l_sql := 'select TRIM(emp_no) , TRIM(EMP_NAME_E) FROM hr."VempDtls" where DESG_TYPE <> 99';

  IF DESGN in (4,5,6,99) then
    IF EMPNO = 213 then
      l_sql := l_sql || ' and emp_no =85';    
    ELSif EMPNO in (341,215,278) then
      l_sql := l_sql || ' and emp_no in(213,215,219,58)';
    ELSif EMPNO in (336,323) then
      l_sql := l_sql || ' and emp_no in(277,219,58)';
    ELSE  
      l_sql := l_sql || ' and dg_code = :1'
                     || ' and emp_no <> :2'
                     || ' and (  DESG_TYPE in (2,3,0,1)'
                     ||      'OR (   dept_code = :3'
                     ||         'and DESG_TYPE in (4,5,6)'
                     ||         'and DESG_TYPE < :4'
                     ||         ')'
                     ||       ')';
      OPEN l_name FOR l_sql USING dg, empno, dept, desgn;
      RETURN;
    END IF;
  ELSif DESGN in (2,3) and EMPNO != 58 then 
    l_sql := l_sql || ' and emp_no=120';
  END IF;

  OPEN  l_name FOR l_sql;
END MANGERLIST;
/
```

Comment: I executed the procedure in SQL developer and I got the result but, When I executed in controller I did not receive the data.